# WordPress Query Posts To Show All & Style Each One

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to include every post onto my index page on WordPress and have each one of them be styled with the included CSS.  I am able to query all of the posts and have them show up, but only the first post is actually styled.  The rest inherit the base h1, h2, p and other generic styles, but they aren't inheriting the "box" class for each one.  All of the information is being thrown into one 'box' class instead of starting a new 'box' class for each post like I would like it to do.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is my code I am using

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="index-float-left">

<div class="box">

<?php query_posts( 'showposts=-1' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> 

        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        <p class="post-date"><?php echo $post_date = get_the_date(); ?></p>

    </div>

</div> <!-- END BOX -->

    </div> <!-- FLOAT BOX BOX -->


    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

     <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with "End Box" and "Fload Box Box". Can you try like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="index-float-left">

<?php query_posts( 'showposts=-1' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>

<div class="box">
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> 
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <p class="post-date"><?php echo $post_date = get_the_date(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- END BOX -->   

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- FLOAT BOX BOX -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: It is still adding all of the content within one "box"

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a lot for the help!  What ended up being the problem?

Comment: @DrewTempleton, I have updated the code, can you check again?

Comment: @DrewTempleton, the problem was in these two lines: `<div class="box">` and `</div> <!-- END BOX -->`. I've just move it to the body of `while` statement.

Comment: @DrewTempleton, if it's ok, than you can close this question by accepting my answer.